# Save a the text from a jTextArea (ie Save As) into a new .txt file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I am busy trying to make a word processor as one of my project and I need the text entered into the jTextArea to be saved as a .txt file with a name and location that the user chooses. note "fc" is the name of i file chooser i have already declared.

```
   public class TextEditor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int count = 2;
    JTextArea n = new JTextArea();
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    public void SaveAs() {

        final JFileChooser SaveAs = new JFileChooser();
        SaveAs.setApproveButtonText("Save");
        int actionDialog = SaveAs.showOpenDialog(this);

        File fileName = new File(SaveAs.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
        try {
            if (fileName == null) {
                return;
            }
            BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            outFile.write(n.getText()); //put in textfile

            outFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need to show us what you have and what you tried. We aren't here to write the code for you we're here to help debug something that you worked on.

Comment: Your method `SaveAs` and your JFileChooser `SaveAs` use the same name, and don't follow the normal Java naming conventions, which is a recipe for confusion...

Comment: what exactly is the problem (aka: your question)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the JTetArea's own write method as this will allow easy writing to file and will handle all line feeds nicely.  For example (and to borrow your code):

```
public class TextEditor extends JFrame {

   int count = 2;
   JTextArea n = new JTextArea();
   final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

   public void SaveAs() {

      final JFileChooser SaveAs = new JFileChooser();
      SaveAs.setApproveButtonText("Save");
      int actionDialog = SaveAs.showOpenDialog(this);
      if (actionDialog != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         return;
      }

      File fileName = new File(SaveAs.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
      BufferedWriter outFile = null;
      try {
         outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

         n.write(outFile);   // *** here: ***

      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (outFile != null) {
            try {
               outFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // one of the few times that I think that it's OK
               // to leave this blank
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```

You've got some bugs in your code.  For e.g. this works,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextEditor extends JFrame {

   int count = 2;
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
   final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

   public TextEditor() {
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
      add(new JPanel(){{add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Save As") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            saveAs();
         }
      }));}}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public void saveAs() {
      FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File", "txt");
      final JFileChooser saveAsFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      saveAsFileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Save");
      saveAsFileChooser.setFileFilter(extensionFilter);
      int actionDialog = saveAsFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
      if (actionDialog != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         return;
      }

      // !! File fileName = new File(SaveAs.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
      File file = saveAsFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      if (!file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
         file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
      }

      BufferedWriter outFile = null;
      try {
         outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

         textArea.write(outFile);

      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (outFile != null) {
            try {
               outFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TextEditor frame = new TextEditor();

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Comment: still does not write the text to the new file, the saved file does not save the text

Comment: @user1267300: "does not work" doesn't tell us much that will allow us to tell you why. If you still need our help, I suggest that you create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please read the link), and show us how it's not working.

Comment: n.write(outFile); does still not write the text to the new file

Answer (score 2):

You seem (though some of your code is missing) to be reading from the chosen file using `FileReader`and then writing to the same file using `FileWriter`. Clearly, this is going around in circles.

You need to call `JTextArea` methods (`getText()` etc) to get the text, then write that to the file.

What is `this.n` ?

Also note that you are catching Exceptions silently with `catch (IOException ex) {}`, i.e. not logging any error - so you won't get any information if something goes wrong.

Finally, you should use `finally` to close your file - if you do it in the `try` block, it won't get closed if there's an Exception.

**Update** (now that Q has been edited): Presumably your JFileChooser is returning a directory. You are then appending ".txt" to it. I don't think this is what you meant. Try printing out `fileName` before writing to it. Please also print out `n.getText()` before writing it, and tell us what you see. Please also put a `println` in teh catch block so you can confirm whether there's an exception thrown.

Comment: so now I have this outFile.write(n.getText()); ('n' being the jTextArea) but still not writing the text to the file what am i missing?

Comment: No idea, since I can't see how you declare and set up `n`. Try updating your question with a little more code. Also you could print out `n.getText()` to confirm that the expected text is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to close your file at the end, so it will write text into.

example:

```
BufferedWriter wr;
            try { wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
                wr.write(edytor.getText());
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Okno.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```